# Unable to use the flutter keyboard visibility package when detecting a softkeyboard on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, multiplatform

I am currently trying to use the [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) package in order to check for a soft-keyboard and dynamically build the page based on whether a keyboard is present.

After having issues with a larger app, I created a bare-bones flutter app with a single screen. I then added the flutter_keyboard_visbility package and placed a keyboard_visibility widget into my page. The issue persists, whenever I try to click on a text field, the field is unable to focus and the page stays in the unfocused state.

I have set my iOS version to iOS 13, the command flutter build iOS is able to run successfully and I have no issues when trying to run the app.

Running the application in verbose doesn't seem to help either.

````
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const TestPage()
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {


  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
        builder: (context, isKeyBoardVisible){
          if (isKeyBoardVisible){
            return Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Keyboard visible"
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  focusNode: _focusNode,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}```
````